# error in my for loop over a hashmap

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

it's my first time to deal with `HashMap`'s and i'm trying to make a simple loop to loop over each key but the code doesn't even enter the `for-loop`...can anyone help me plz?

```
for(int i=0; i< ackPkts.size()-1; i++){
    System.out.println("yasmin");
    if (ackPkts.get(i).getAckNo() == ackPkts.get(i-1).getAckNo()){   
        System.out.println("there's a retransmissionS here");
    }else{
        v = value.indexOf(ackPkts.get(i).getAckNo() -1);
    }
}
```

it doesn't even print ***yasmin*** !

Comment: i of course initialized the hashmap ackPkts earlier in the code.

Comment: Is it a HashMap or a List? Your code treats ackPkts as if it is a List.

Comment: You can't access values in the HashMap by index (unless the key is Integer and there are entries in the Map for all keys from 0 to size()-1, in which case it would make more sense to use an ArrayList).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot iterate a map like an `Array` or a `List`, even if your keys are `Integer` and consecutive it is highly discouraged.

```
for(int i=0; i< ackPkts.size()-1; i++){   // WRONG!
```

To iterate each entry of a map use the `entrySet()` method:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

---

Also as noted in others answers, there is plenty of mistakes because of `-1` you used with size, but this will be avoided iterating the `entrySet` of your `Map` ;)

Comment: okay but if i use entryset[] still i will  not be able to compare values which what i mainly want to do then if i found values not matching  i return the key

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet that you have mentioned is not clear enough to understand what has to be done inside the loop.

Hope this would help you.

```
    Set set = ackPkts.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();     
         while(i.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
         System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
         System.out.println(me.getValue());
         }
```

This is the way to loop over the HashMap.

Comment: i tried that already but i want to compare values inside a huge sized hashmap and it will be hard to use getValue() and store it and compare it with the rest of the values in the hashmap in order to figure out if there is a matching value or not ...it will have a very high complexity and i don't want that..any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop condition is wrong.

**It should be :**

`for(int i=0; i< ackPkts.size(); i++) {`

And still if it does not print anything, then it means that `ackPkts` is empty.